# How to center this elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found a great snippet of code but when I tried to modify it to suit my needs I was unable to quite get it right, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

The snippet in question is this one: [code](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/content-in-bootstrap-tabs)

I only want three tabs and for them to be centered,kinda as the example in the snippet only had tab 2, 3 and 4, so far I suspect this is what controls that part of the style:

```
.board .nav-tabs {
    position: relative;
    /* border-bottom: 0; */
    /* width: 80%; */
    margin: 40px auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: There are 5 tabs(li) are available and have a width of 20% ie,100/5 = 20,
if you want 3 tabs give width of 33.33% ie,100/3=33.33.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this snippet http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/40NRR

I used display flex and then set a percentage width of the `.nav-tabs` to get it centered. Also some other minor styling like changing where the `border-bottom` lives.

Edit: The snippet isn't displaying it seems.

```
.board .nav-tabs {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 0;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.board .nav-tabs > li {
    flex: 1;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I cannot seem to be able to acess the url you provided.

Comment: It work beautifully! My only qualm is that the little arrow li:after is now offset, did that happen in yours as well? Editing question to show.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your solution

```
.board {
  text-align: center;
} 
.board .nav-tabs {
  position: relative;
  display : inline-block ;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, but it is close I edited the question to show how it looks now.

Comment: I see that didn't work because the float in bootstrap. To use this solution just add `float: none` to the `.board .nav-tabs` rule.